# Which Specflow version supports .Net framework 4.7.1

Tags: .net, specflow, .net-4.7.1

We are using Specflow for most of our tests. We are trying to upgrade to the .Net framework 4.7.1. Is there a specflow version that works with this framwork version, or am I whipping a dead horse?

Answer (score 0):

**SpecFlow 2** targets .NET 4.5, i.e. **it works with .NET 4.5 or higher**.

You should therefore not upgrade to the new version in projects using earlier versions of the .NET framework.

In this case, you should continue using SpecFlow 1.9 until you are ready to move to .NET 4.5. or higher

[Source](https://specflow.org/updating-to-specflow-2/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I 'm on Specflow version 2.2.x; I 'm moving from .Net framework 4.6 to 4.7.1. But the latest version of specflow 2.4.1 does not play nice (on my machine). If it should I'm having a local problem. If it is not supposed to, I can quit trying...

Comment: It should work with .NET 4.7.1.  I am one of the developers of SpecFlow.

Comment: @AndreasWillich: Correct you are. It is working fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas Willich pointed out in his comment. Specflow 2.4.1 plays nice in/with .Net Framework 4.7.2.